# Все логи пишутся в один файл log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Решил я логировать запросы в моем приложении, сделал, работает, но теперь все логи spring'a которые раньше просто выводились в консоль - в одном файле с теми логами которые пишу я, можно это как то исправить ?

Конфигурация log4j

```
# Уровень логирования
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Апендер для работы с файлами
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
# Путь где будет создаваться лог файл
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\admin\\IdeaProjects\\Animal-Clinic\\src\\main\\resources\\logs\\log_file.log
# Указываем максимальный размер файла с логами
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
# Конфигурируем шаблон вывода логов в файл
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Вот огромный лог файл, я логировал последнюю строчку, остальное все spring'a
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: погуглите конфигурирование log4j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная ситуация нормальна для твоей конфигурации. Т.к. `spring` использует `slf4j`, то предположу, что раньше у тебя не было в проекте коннектора `slf4j` - `log4j`. После неких манипуляций он появился, и `slf4j` теперь работает поверх `log4j`. Чтобы вернуть именно логи `spring` обратно в консоль, попробуй следующую конфигурацию

```
# Уровень логирования
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Апендер для работы с файлами
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
# Путь где будет создаваться лог файл
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\admin\\IdeaProjects\\Animal-Clinic\\src\\main\\resources\\logs\\log_file.log
# Указываем максимальный размер файла с логами
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
# Конфигурируем шаблон вывода логов в файл
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# теперь настройка spring-логов
#убирает spring-логи из root-логов
log4j.additivity.org.springframework=false
#настройка логгера для консоли
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#настройка вывода spring-логов в консоль
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO, stdout
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает!